# Homework that is like a caesar cipher involving two char[]

Tags: java, arrays

There are two char[]. ENGLISHARR has the alphabet stored in the array from A-Z followed by a-z and SAURIANARR the alphabet being scrambled while still maintaining Uppercase followed by Undercase both of the arrays exclude M and m as well as special characters such as a ? or ! so they will be used as is . There will a String variable that will store a sentence in English and Translate the sentence to a made up language called Saurian that is used in the video game called Star Fox Adventures or Saurian to English.

I am having trouble translating the the String and converting it to the other language.

I have tried using two for loops, one that continues for the length of the word that is going to be translated and the other that takes the goes through the letters of word and stores the letter after it has been translated. After the for loops I would have a if statement that builds a String that would store the Letter that has been translated if it was found in the array.

I have tried using Arrays.asList().indexOf(); to see if that would store the value of the index of the Array where the letter was found in. And then print the char store in the opposite array by using the stored index.

My teacher also said that this was the hardest assignment of the semester. This is my first java class and I have been trying to learn outside of the class. This is also why the for loops do not work properly. I am still trying to learn Java so I am sorry if I made beginners mistakes.

```
public class as5
{

//English alphabet
    public static final char[] ENGLISHARR = {'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z','a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'};

//Saurian alphabet
public static final char[] SAURIANARR = {'U','R','S','T','O','V','W','X','A','Z','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','J','K','I','L','N','P','O','Q','u','r','s','t','o','v','w','x','a','z','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','j','k','i','l','n','p','o','q'};


public static final int ARRLENGTH = ENGLISHARR.length;

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    //String that will be converted into a char[]
    String word = "Hello World";

    // String that will be used to store the word after it has been translated and will be built using the for loops
    String saurianToEnglish = "";

    //Character Array that turns the given string into a char array
    char[] str = word.toCharArray();


    // For loop that loops as long as the input is Ex. "Hello World" is 11 characters long
    for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++)
    {
        //For loop that should loop through the ENGLISHARR and build the word
        for (int j = 0; j < ARRLENGTH; j++)
        {
            // indexOfYellow should store the index number for which the letter in the string was located in the array.
            int indexOfYellow = Arrays.asList(ENGLISHARR).indexOf(str[i]);
            System.out.println(indexOfYellow);
            int index = str[i];

            //Should Check if the character at index i is present in ENGLISHARR then it will save it to saurianToEnglish
            if (indexOfYellow == -1)
            {
                saurianToEnglish += SAURIANARR[index];

                 //This is just here to see if the if statement passed
                System.out.println("saurianToEnglish PASS   " + saurianToEnglish);
            }
            else
            {
                //This is just here to see if the if statement failed
                System.out.println("saurianToEnglish FAIL   " + indexOfYellow);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

For example if the input was "Hello World"

ENGLISHARR[1] = 'H'

Which needs to be translated into saurian which would be

SAURIANARR[1] = 'X'

so the total input "Hello World" should be translated to "Xocce Gebvt"

```
// Add while loop here 

if (indexOfYellow == -1)

                    saurianToEnglish += SAURIANARR[index];

                     //This is just here to see if the if statement passed
                    System.out.println("saurianToEnglish PASS   " + saurianToEnglish);
                }
                else
                {
                    //This is just here to see if the if statement failed
                    System.out.println("saurianToEnglish FAIL   " + indexOfYellow);
                }
```

If i add a while while(index < 51) with index being int index = str[i]; loop before the if statement the program will run for a while so I know something is wrong here.

My teacher also gave me us a hint for how the for loops should be structured.

for() ---> which iterates through the given word

```
for() ---> which iterates through the ENGLISHARR to check if the letter is held in the array.

    if(found)
    {
    }
    else
    {
    }
```

This is the code with the while loop that will actually run.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class as5
{
    //Character array to check if another array contains one of the following
    public static final char[] ENGLISHARR = {'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z','a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'};
    public static final char[] SAURIANARR = {'U','R','S','T','O','V','W','X','A','Z','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','J','K','I','L','N','P','O','Q','u','r','s','t','o','v','w','x','a','z','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','j','k','i','l','n','p','o','q'};
    public static final int ARRLENGTH = ENGLISHARR.length;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //String that will be converted into a char[]
        String word = "Hello World";

        // String that will hold the index of the
        String saurianToEnglish = "";

        //Character Array that takes turns the given string into a char array
        char[] str = word.toCharArray();


        // For loop that loops as long as the input is Ex. "Hello World" is 11 characters long
        for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++)
        {
            //For loop that should loop through the ENGLISHARR and build the word
            for (int j = 0; j < ARRLENGTH; j++)
            {

                int indexOfYellow = Arrays.asList(ENGLISHARR).indexOf(str[i]);
                System.out.println(indexOfYellow);
                int index = str[i];

                //Should Check if the character at index i is present in ENGLISHARR then it will save it to indexOfYellow
                while(index < 51)

                    if (indexOfYellow == -1)
                    {
                        saurianToEnglish += SAURIANARR[str[i]];

                        System.out.println("saurianToEnglish PASS   " + saurianToEnglish);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //saurianToEnglish += SAURIANARR[indexOfYellow];
                        System.out.println("saurianToEnglish FAIL   " + indexOfYellow);
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- No need to convert `word` to array, and just use `charAt()` method to
  access the characters.
- You cannot create a List of primitive types, so `Arrays.asList(ENGLISHARR)` will create a List of `char[]`. Instead of `char[]`, use `Character[]`.
- It should be `if (indexOfYellow != -1)`
- You should use `indexOfYellow` the get the character `SAURIANARR[indexOfYellow]`;
- No need for inner loop
- If no character found, such as whitespace, just append it to the string.

  ```
  // English alphabet
  public static final Character[] ENGLISHARR = { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'N', 'O', 'P',
          'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k',
          'l', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z' };

  // Saurian alphabet
  public static final Character[] SAURIANARR = { 'U', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'O', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'A', 'Z', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F',
          'G', 'H', 'J', 'K', 'I', 'L', 'N', 'P', 'O', 'Q', 'u', 'r', 's', 't', 'o', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'a', 'z', 'b',
          'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'i', 'l', 'n', 'p', 'o', 'q' };


  public static void main(String... args) {
      String word = "Hello World";

      // String that will be used to store the word after it has been
      // translated and will be built using the for loops
      String saurianToEnglish = "";

      // For loop that loops as long as the input is Ex. "Hello World" is 11
      // characters long
      for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {           
          // indexOfYellow should store the index number for which the letter in the string was located in the array.
          int indexOfYellow = Arrays.asList(ENGLISHARR).indexOf(word.charAt(i));
          System.out.println(indexOfYellow);

          // Should Check if the character at index i is present in ENGLISHARR then it will save it to saurianToEnglish
          if (indexOfYellow != -1) {
              saurianToEnglish += SAURIANARR[indexOfYellow];

              // This is just here to see if the if statement passed
              System.out.println("saurianToEnglish PASS   " + saurianToEnglish);
          } else {
              saurianToEnglish += word.charAt(i);

              // This is just here to see if the if statement failed
              System.out.println("saurianToEnglish FAIL   " + indexOfYellow);
          }
      }

  }
  ```